# Reconstructing a partition from its character

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, polynomials

Given a solid partition $\rho=\{\pi_1, \pi_2, ..\}$, where $\pi_a$ are plane partitions such that $\pi_{a+1} \subset \pi_a$, we can compute its character, which is a sum of monomials with non-negative powers of $q_1,..,q_4$. Given the character we can recover the solid partition, in a $1:1$ fashion.The function computing the character is

```
character[p_, x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := Sum[x1^(i - 1) x2^(j - 1) x3^(k - 1) x4^(m - 1), {i, 1, Length[p]}, {j, 1, Length[p[[i]]]}, {k, 1, Length[p[[i, j]]]}, {m, 1, p[[i, j, k]]}]
```

For example, the character of the partition `{{{2}, {1}}}` is given by $1 + q_2 + q_4$.

How do I construct a function that, given the character as input, gives as output the solid partition that has such character?

What kglr proposes almost works, for example consider the partition `{{{1}}, {{1}}}`: it has character 1+x1, and the function `toPartition[1+x1]` gives back `{{{{1}}}, {{{1}}}}`. But consider another example: the partition `{{{2}}}` has character 1+x4, but `toPartition[1+x4]` gives `{{{{1, 1}}}}`. There should be a way of eliminating the innermost nesting level by summing over its entries, somehow.

I now believe that `Total[CoefficientList[c_, {x1, x2, x3, x4}], {-1}]` does the job.

Comment: perhaps `toPartition[c_] := List /@ Total /@ CoefficientList[c, {x2, x4}]`?

Comment: is `{0}` allowed as a member of $\rho$?

Comment: @kglr if you want, we define the empty partition to have character zero. The partition with one box {{{1}}} has character 1.

Comment: @kglr if a certain $\pi_a=0$ we just don't write it, as all the following are zero as well

Comment: jj_p, it seems `List /@ Total /@ CoefficientList[c, Variables[c]]` works for all cases except where the last entry is `{0}` , can you please check?

Comment: @kglr thanks, I don't care so much about the empty case, but still it gives one nesting level too much, right? see my edit above

Comment: @kglr Many thanks for your initial suggestion, I now believe that what i write above is correct.

Comment: jj_p, perhaps `DeleteCases[
 Total[CoefficientList[c, {x1, x2, x3, x4}], {-1}], {0}, Infinity]` ?

Comment: @kglr as long as i give in input something that is a character (excluded perhaps 0), then i think also without deletecases it gives me back the correct result. thank you for helping